# Render lips with ARKit and iPhoneX

Tags: xcode, scenekit, arkit, scnnode

I have been trying to render lips using ARKit.
This is what I have tried:

1. Create and import an SCN node from a collada dae format file.
2. Place the node in SCNScene with SceneKit editor.

I am using ARFaceAnchor.BlendShapes to figure out the movements in the lips. However, I am not able to associate the movements with the lips node that I have.

1. How can I associate part of the node with each individual movement? Do I need to create multiple nodes for each part of the lips?
2. How can I figure out exactly where the lips fit on the face? (How to get the face coordinates for the lips)?

Thanks

Comment: did u got the solution for this ?

Comment: Any update on this?